# В чём разница между list.clear() и list = []?

Tags: python-3.x, методы

Писал только что код, и не мог найти ошибку пока не изменил list.clear() на list = []. 
вот код на питоне:

```
def reverse_ascending(items):
if len(items) == 2:
    return list(reversed(items))
stack = []
s = []
count = 1
while count < len(items):
    if items[count-1] < items[count]:
        s.insert(0, items[count-1])
    elif items[count-1] > items[count]:
        s.insert(0, items[count-1])
        stack.append(s)
        s = []
    else:
        stack.append([items[count-1]])
    if count == len(items)-1:
        s.insert(0, items[count])
        stack.append(s)
    count += 1
return [i for x in stack for i in x] if len(items) > 1 else items


print("Example:")
print(reverse_ascending([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

# These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
print(reverse_ascending([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
print(reverse_ascending([5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3])) # [10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]
```

Задание: Создайте и верните новый итерируемый элемент, содержащий те же элементы, что и итерируемые элементы аргумента, но с обратным порядком элементов внутри каждого максимального строго восходящего подсписка.
Еле-еле нашёл что если заменить s.clear() на s = [] то в stack добавляется список из s и сохраняется. НО, если я напишу s.clear() то stack тоже удаляется. можете побробывать. Почему очистка списка s затрагивает список stack?

Answer (score 2):

Разница простая.

`lis.clear()` очищает массив сохраняя ссылку. Если где-то есть другие ссылки на этот же объект, они теперь ссылаются на пустой массив.

`list = []` - создание нового объекта. Другие ссылки продолжают ссылаться на старый (заполненный) массив. Манипуляции с `list` на старый массив не повлияют.